# Laravel Eloquent in many to many relation limit relational data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have many to many relations. Product, Category and category_product as pivot. I want to fetch Product through Category but I need each Category 10 Product.

here is my query

```
 Category::with(['grocery_product')->get();
```

Category model :

```
   public function grocery_product(): BelongsToMany
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->limit(10);
   }
```

but here limit is not working. if I remove limit(10) then I get all products associated with that Category.

Note: I have tried with take(10) function also.

How to fetch each category's 10 products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Default laravel doesn't have any out of the Box solution for the scenario.

So  you can use the [eloquent-eager-limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit) by [staudenmeir](https://github.com/staudenmeir/)

You can do something like this.

```
//Category Model
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
  public function grocery_product(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

Inside `Product` model use the same trait

```
//Product Model
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
```

In Controller.

```
//to get latest 5 `grocery_product` on each category
$fiveGroceryOfEachProduct = Category::with(['grocery_product' => function ($query) {
    $query->latest()->limit(5);
}])->get();
```

Calling limit method without using this pacakage will apply the **limti** on overall query. Not on each Model.

You can view the github issue [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18014)

Edit for Query **Compatibility** issue

So as the pacakage [suggests](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit#compatibility). Please set

```
'strict' => false,
```

**In your config/database.php file, set 'strict' => false, for the MariaDB/MySql connection.** And  make sure to restart your dev server

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much :)

Comment: If the solution helps you kindly accept my answer